# Get all values for a given field based on another field

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have some documents contains fields: id, size, etc

And I want find all the possible size where id = 1 or 2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use terms query with source filtering. Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "size": 1
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "size": 2
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "size": 3
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "_source": "size",
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66381642",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "size": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66381642",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "size": 2
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @jason135 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the possible sizes of that Ids then you should use an aggregation.

```
POST your_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sizes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "size"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will be the unique size with the amount of docs with that size

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sizes" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```